# How to connect to postgresql target in google data fusion

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-data-fusion

I'm using BigQuery as source and need to load some data to postgres in a different project. Whenever I try connecting, I'm getting the error saying failed to validate table schema.

error: "Exception while trying to validate schema of database table '{tablename}' for connection 'jdbc:postgresql://{actual ip}:5432/public'"

Comment: do you have authorized the network of Data Fusion?

Comment: yes, both are in different projects, but have added proxy of destination in source project network

Comment: what do you mean by proxy? A compute engine that act as proxy?

Comment: Yes...Every packet of data flows through the proxy network, ie compute engine.

Comment: Are you able to connect directly from the proxy? By using the proxy from another VM? The aim here is to narrow the location of the issue

Comment: Both source and destination are in different VPCs, and I have a the destination (Postgresql) is installed in one of the VM. We have configured the proxy of destination in source VPC